# Law of Demeter & Factory Pattern

Tags: c#

I would like to know if the below secnerio is a violation of Law of Demeter.

1. I have 2 factory classes `CarFactory` and `BusFactory`.
2. `CarFactory` will return objects of type `IVehicle`.
3. Now I have another wrapper factory, say `VehicleFactory`.
4. `VehicleFactory` will return back `CarFactory` or 'BusFactory'
5. The main class will first invoke `VehcileFactory` to return the `CarFactory` or `BusFactory`.
6. And then the `CarFactory` or `BusFactory` will return a Car (say Maruthi) or Bus type (say Volvo).
7. Then the method of Car of Bus Type is invoked.

Below is the sample code

**Class: `Maruthi`**

```
public class Maruthi:IVehicle
{
    public void MakeVehicle()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Maruthi..");
    }
}
```

**Class: `CarFactory`**

```
public class CarFactory:IVehicleFactory
{
    IVehicle car;
    public IVehicle GetVehicle(string type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case "Maruthi":
                car= new Maruthi();
                break;
        }
        return car;
    }
}
```

**Class: `VehicleFactory`**

```
public class VehicleFactory
{

    public static IVehicleFactory GetVehicleFactory (string Factorytype)
    {
        IVehicleFactory VehFact=null;
        switch (Factorytype)
        {
            case "Car":
                VehFact = new CarFactory();
                break;
        }
        return VehFact;
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IVehicleFactory vehFact = VehicleFactory.GetVehicleFactory("Car");
        IVehicle veh = vehFact.GetVehicle("Maruthi");
        veh.MakeVehicle();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

**iVehicle**

```
namespace LOD_ViolationorNot
{
   public interface IVehicle
    {
       void MakeVehicle();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see `ICar` or `IBus`. If you have working code - consider [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hi I have added the interface. The interfact is IVehicle. Then Maruthi is the car which implements IVehicle. Haven't implemented a Bus as its implementation will also be same as that of Maruthi

Comment: It looks like the two layers between the client and actual created entity are unnecessary. Yes, then, I would say the design here violates the Law of Demeter.

Comment: @WiktorZychla the Law of Demeter expressed that the function has access to the objects it created itself. I think there is no difference between creating an object using new keyword or using a method that we know it only creates an object (because it is an implementation for a creational pattern). They are same in higher level of abstraction. So I think the code in the main method, does not violates the Law of Demeter (but it can be designed in a more robust way)